# High thread count in java thread dump

Tags: java, wildfly, cpu-usage

My java web application running on `wildfly-9.0.1.Final` sometimes it consumes very high memory and CPU.
I got the thread dump for this time and found more than 7K thread with an identical thread with below stack trace.

```
pool-47940-thread-1 - priority:5 - threadId:0x000000029ad3f800 - nativeId:0xfad0 - state:WAITING
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for <0x00000007a7d1fbe0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Locked ownable synchronize
```

I analyze thread dump using [this](http://fastthread.io)

Here is a screenshot for the same. 
[image]

[image]

I used below code in my application many times

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
//business logic
// This will make the executor accept no new threads and finish all existing threads in the queue
executor.shutdown();
// Wait until all threads are finish
while (!executor.isTerminated()) {

}
```

Is ablow code cause any issue?

Are this threads root cause for high memory and CPU usage?

Comment: A pool with 7315 threads sure makes one think that something is wrong.

Comment: Yes, the name of the thread is in similar pattern `pool-47940-thread-1, pool-47940-thread-2, pool-47940-thread-3`. But I can not find root cause

Comment: I used `ExecutorService` with 3 thread count

Comment: Yeah, well that pool has 7000 threads, so it's not the same one.

Comment: But, all threads are in waiting status.

Comment: Yeah, they are. There's still 7000 of them. If they're all waiting, do you need 7000 of them?

Comment: Generally speaking you're suggested not to use your own threads or executors in Java EE applications. Since WildFly is a Java EE 7 container you could just use the ManagedExecutorServer and have the resource injected.

Comment: I used `while (!executor.isTerminated()){}` because I need the result of all task before moving to next line of code.I need to execute all 3 thread parallelly and have to wait for all task to complete.

Comment: did you ever figure out the source of this issue? i am having nearly the exact same thread dump in my application right now and i cant figure out where these threads are coming from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my above code, I used `while (!executor.isTerminated()){}` to wait for all task finished their job. This while loop uses CPU until all task finished, this may cause high CPU issue.

I modified my code as below. This solved my high CPU problem.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
executor.shutdown();
executor.invokeAll(listOfTask);  // invokAll method will wait untill all task finished, No while loop here
```

for more information [read this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

Answer (score 0):

Huge amount of thread may cause problem with memory, but if all of them in `WAITING` state then they doesn't consume processor ticks.

I suggest you to solve your problems one by one.

To find out where all memory is stuck you need to get memory dump, and analyze it with some tool like MAT.

CPU consumption problem can by analyzed with `jconsole` or `jvisualvm` from SDK. Both of them have profiler tool.